Determine the asymptotic complexity of a function
This is a homework problem I have. I could not find whether it was against the rules or not to post such a question. I cannot figure this one out. I would appreciate help in understanding why the answer is what it is.
I can say with confidence that in this case, we would be concerned with θ as being the most precise description of the asymptotic complexity since the loops never terminate early.
I understand that the outer for loop will always run n times, and that the inner for loop will run less times as i increases.
The answer would then be θ(n * running time of inner loop).
I think that either ∑ from k=1 to n of n(n+1)/2 or the harmonic series ∑ from k = i to N of i/1 could be useful here, but I don't know how to apply either. We went over relatively simple examples in class and I understand those, but not this one.
void function(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j += i) {
            std::cout << "*";
        }
    }
}

Making a table with theoretical values for i and j when n is a certain value and trying to find a mathematical relationship between i and j.
Ex: say n = 3.



i
j




1
1


1
2


1
3


2
1


2
3


3
1




Your total complexity is
(n / 1) + (n / 2) + ... + (n / n) =
n * ((1 / 1) + (1 / 2) + ... (1 / n)) =
n * (ln(n) + 0.577) which is roughly nlogn.
The reason is that
(1 / 1) + (1 / 2) + ... + (1 / n)
is known as the harmonic series, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Partial_sums)

Can I ask how you arrived at ((1 / 1) + (1 / 2) + ... ( 1 / n)) from the inner loop? I could take what you said at face value of it just being the harmonic series, but I'd like to understand the reasoning of how you got there.

@HailVelkekia because whatever the value of i is, the step size is i, so you have n / i steps. Since i = 1, ..., n, you get (n / 1) + (n / 2), ... + (n / n), where we can notice that each item is multiplied by n, so it's a common multiplier, hence we reach n * ((1 / 1) + (1 / 2) + ... + (1 / n)), which is the linear n due to the outer loop and a harmonic series for the inner loop.
